# How to run seaweedFS as a daemon?

Tags: seaweedfs, weed-fs

Started and tested a multi-server [seaweedFS](https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs) setup as below which is working great:

```
./weed server -dir=/VolA,/VolB -s3 -s3.config=weed.json -s3.port=9001 -master.defaultReplication="010" -master.peers=ip1:9333,ip2:9333,ip3:9333 -ip=ip1 -dataCenter=ABC -rack=A -volume.max=100
./weed server -dir=/VolA,/VolB -s3 -s3.config=weed.json -s3.port=9001 -master.defaultReplication="010" -master.peers=ip1:9333,ip2:9333,ip3:9333 -ip=ip2 -dataCenter=ABC -rack=B -volume.max=100
./weed server -dir=/VolA,/VolB -s3 -s3.config=weed.json -s3.port=9001 -master.defaultReplication="010" -master.peers=ip1:9333,ip2:9333,ip3:9333 -ip=ip3 -dataCenter=ABC -rack=C -volume.max=100
```

However, I don't see any documentation on how to keep seaweedFS running as a daemon.
I.e.: currently I'm running weed in a remote shell. Closing the shell shutsdown weed.

Any pointers much appreciated

Comment: I do not know that either. :)

Comment: @chrislusf: Ha! Seeing you're the creator, I'm pretty sure I must be barking up the wrong tree ;). So asked differently, what's the standard solution to just keeping weed humming along?

Comment: There should be many ways to daemonize a process. Here is one that I found.

http://software.clapper.org/daemonize/

Comment: Cheers. I somehow thought weed would something out of the box to run as a daemon, since everyone would do that in production (?) . But yeah I'll figure it out myself. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you please share your approach? I also want to know the details.

Comment: @chrislusf : sure thing, see answer

Comment: This Wiki page could be of help: https://github.com/seaweedfs/seaweedfs/wiki/Server-Startup-Setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by hand-rolling a systemd service.

For each node do: (obviously, replace with your own weed specific commands)

```
# 1. Move `weed` to some directory the startup service can access. I used `/usr/local/bin/weed/`. Include `weed` and `weed.json` in that directory (ymmv) 


mkdir /usr/local/bin/weed
mv weed /usr/local/bin/weed/weed
mv weed.json /usr/local/bin/weed/weed.json


# 2. Create a systemd service config: 

cat > /etc/systemd/system/seaweedmaster.service <<EOM

[Unit]
Description=SeaweedFS Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/weed/weed server -dir=/VolA,/VolB -s3 -s3.config=weed.json -s3.port=9001 -master.defaultReplication="010" -master.peers=ip1:9333,ip2:9333,ip3:9333 -ip=ip1 -dataCenter=ABC -rack=A -volume.max=100
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/weed/
SyslogIdentifier=seaweedfs-master

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOM


# 3. Reload, enable and start 

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable seaweedmaster
sudo systemctl start seaweedmaster



# 4. logging the output, one of many options: 

journalctl -u seaweedmaster.service -b --no-pager
```